# How can I run tests from a Visual Studio Extension?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I want to create an extension for Visual Studio that will run tests and show results on Test Explorer.

But I have no idea how to get the Test Explorer `ToolWindowPane` (is it a tool window pane?) and how to add tests to it.

Can someone provide an example and/or provide some information on how to achieve it?

Comment: Multiple extensions already provide this functionality.  Is there some missing feature in existing testing addons?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/07/31/writing-a-visual-studio-2012-unit-test-adapter.aspx

Comment: @Amy there is only one that provides Unit Tests for `TypeScript` and it not getting updated (so soon) to run with the latest version which supports generics syntax. If I could at least understand more how extension works I could customize it for me.

Comment: Yeah, @cadrell0's post shows how to do it. The Test Explorer was designed to be extensible, so it has it's own API for doing it directly.